# Single checkbox in tableview iOS Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Im working on tableview single multiple checkbox functionality. I have done the Multiple checkbox in tableview. But i have no idea about the single selection checkbox in tableview. can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain further, what do you mean by Single Multiple Checkbox functionality?

Comment: Can you provide some code, or image to make your description clearer?

Comment: Sorry, I have 2 functionalities. 1)single selection 2)Multiple selection checkboxes. @Munahil

Comment: By single selection checkbox, you mean something like radio button?

Comment: Yes, like radio button

Answer (score 0):

Keep in a variable the current selected choice.
On **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** display checked image if the current indexPath.row is equal to this variable, otherwise display the image for unchecked.

Then, in **tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** - store the new selected cell in this variable and do a **[tableview reloadData]**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `allowsMultipleSelection` property of `UITableView`.

For Single selection

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
```

For Multiple selection

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```